# When does class attribute initialization code run in python?

Tags: python

There is a `class` attribute `spark` in our `AnalyticsWriter` class:

```
class AnalyticsWriter:

    spark = SparkSession.getActiveSession()  # this is not getting executed
```

I noticed that this code is *not* being executed before a certain *class method* is run.  Note: it has been verified that there is already an active `SparkSession` available in the process: so the init code is simply not being executed

```
    @classmethod
    def measure_upsert(
        cls
    ) -> DeltaTable:

        assert AnalyticsWriter.spark, "AnalyticsWriter requires \
             an active SparkSession"
```

I come from jvm-land (java/scala) and in those places the class level initialization code happens before any method invocations. What is the equivalent in python?

Comment: Is it possible that the "certain class method" is static..?

Comment: "I noticed that this code is not being executed before a certain class method is run" - you've misdiagnosed the problem. In Python, `SparkSession.getActiveSession()` would execute so early the `AnalyticsWriter` class doesn't even *exist* yet. No class methods could possibly be executed first.

Comment: If the initialization really hadn't happened, you wouldn't be getting an assertion failure. You'd be getting an `AttributeError: type object 'AnalyticsWriter' has no attribute 'spark'`.

Comment: @user2357112  Please clarify your comment in terms of the sequencing.  (1) The SparkSession is being initialized in a different class before `AnalyticsWriter` is ever referenced.  (2) Then the `AnalyticsWriter.measure_upsert()` is invoked by a client. At that point in JVM-land the `class` level initlizations will occur including the line shown.  Please elaborate on your comment in terms of that sequence.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects: `spark = SparkSession.getActiveSession()` happens before (1), assuming the file containing the class definition is imported before (1). Python doesn't do Java-style class-loading. Classes aren't loaded on use. A `class` statement is imperative, like an assignment statement, or a function call. If you had a `print(1)` before the class definition and a `print(2)` after it, the class body, including `spark = SparkSession.getActiveSession()`, would execute between the two `print`s.

Comment: It can't happen before (1) because that is done before `AnalyticsWriter` is even referenced

Comment: @WestCoastProjects: Python doesn't care. Java would care. Python doesn't. The body of a Python `class` statement is executed when the `class` statement is executed, not when something else tries to use the class.

Comment: [Here's](https://ideone.com/TxFZmN) a simple example where nothing references the class at all, but the class body still executes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class attributes are initialized at the moment they are hit, during class definition, so the line containing the `getActiveSession()` call is run before the class is even fully defined.

```
class AnalyticsWriter:
    spark = SparkSession.getActiveSession()
    # The code has been run here
    
    # ... other definitions that occur after spark exists ...
# class is complete here
```

I suspect the code is doing *something*, just not what you expect. You can confirm that it is in fact run with a cheesy hack like:

```
class AnalyticsWriter:
    spark = (SparkSession.getActiveSession(), print("getActiveSession called", flush=True))[0]
```

which just makes a `tuple` of the result of your call and an eager `print`, then discards the meaningless result from the `print`; you should see the output from the `print` immediately, before you can get around to calling class methods.

Comment: I thought that i had put a breakpoint on that line already, but wil double check (and use the printing).  I do use tuples for printing things at times since few python constructs support chaining and/or side effects

Comment: oh it _does_ stop there. my bad.  I'll award when i'm allowed (2 mins tick tock)